# Python objects as userdata in ctypes callback functions

Tags: python, callback, ctypes, user-data

The C function `myfunc` operates on a larger chunk of data. The results are returned in chunks to a callback function:

```
int myfunc(const char *data, int (*callback)(char *result, void *userdata), void *userdata);
```

Using **ctypes**, it's no big deal to call `myfunc` from Python code, and to have the results being returned to a Python callback function. This callback work fine.

```
myfunc = mylib.myfunc
myfunc.restype = c_int
myfuncFUNCTYPE = CFUNCTYPE(STRING, c_void_p)
myfunc.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char), callbackFUNCTYPE, c_void_p]

def mycb(result, userdata):
    print result
    return True

input="A large chunk of data."
myfunc(input, myfuncFUNCTYPE(mycb), 0)
```

But, is there any way to give a Python object (say a list) as userdata to the callback function? In order to store away the result chunks, I'd like to do e.g.:

```
def mycb(result, userdata):
    userdata.append(result)

userdata=[]
```

But I have no idea how to cast the Python list to a c_void_p, so that it can be used in the call to myfunc.

My current workaround is to implement a linked list as a ctypes structure, which is quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could use the [Python C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/) to do that... maybe you could use a PyObject pointer.

**edit**: As the op pointed out in the comments, there's already a `py_object` type readily available in ctypes, so the solution is to create first a `ctypes.py_object` object from the python list and then casting it to `c_void_p` to pass it as an argument to the C function (I think this step might be unnecessary as a parameter typed as `void*` should accept any pointer, and it would be faster to pass just a `byref`). In the callback, the reverse steps are done (casting from the void pointer to a pointer to `py_object` and then getting the value of the contents).

A workaround could be to use a closure for your callback function so it already knows in which list it has to append the items...

```
myfunc = mylib.myfunc
myfunc.restype = c_int
myfuncFUNCTYPE = CFUNCTYPE(STRING)
myfunc.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char), callbackFUNCTYPE]


def mycb(result, userdata):
    userdata.append(result)

input="A large chunk of data."
userdata = []
myfunc(input, myfuncFUNCTYPE(lambda x: mycb(x, userdata)))
```

Comment: Well, the nice thing about ctypes is that everything can be done in plain Python. So the Python C API seems to be a step back. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I meant the option could be creating a ctypes proxy of a C-API PyObject struct, that should be the internal representation of any Python object and passing it around...

Comment: Strange. Your workaround with a closure works fine on Linux, but the same program crashes on Windows.

Comment: Have you noticed he change in the signature of the callback function and changed that accordingly in your C files?

Comment: Nope. That's certainly the problem. I wondered why it worked without the change on Linux.

Comment: But I found the solution I was looking for: `cUserdata=ctypes.cast(pointer(ctypes.py_object(pyUserdata)), c_void_p)` and in the callback: `pyUserdata=ctypes.cast(cUserdata,POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value`. I guess that's what had in mind with the Python C API?

Comment: About the first question, it probably has to do with the calling conventions, by examining what happened I'd say the parameter in Linux was expected in a register and in Windows in the stack (and as it was missing, the stack was corrupted at some point). Is your Linux 64 bit and your Windows 32 bit?

Comment: About the second, that's more or less what I was suggesting, using the C internal representation of the Python object... Luckily enough, ctypes already had it implemented and you didn't have to write your own wrapper and some C code to get the actual pointer.

Comment: Both 32 bit. But in fact, the Windows library uses WINFUNCTYPE, while the Linux version uses CFUNCTYPE.

Comment: Would you mind to update your answer with the py_object? Again, thanks for the hint!