# Can I pass a Python "self" object to a C function as c_void_p and cast to original type for use in a callback?

Tags: python, c, callback, ctypes, self

Using ctypes to interface my python3 code with a C API.  One of the C functions registers a callback function– i.e. it takes a function pointer to the callback and a `void* userdata` to be made available in that callback.

```
// typedef and C function in myClibrary.so
typedef void(__cdecl *callback_function_type)(void*);
int RegCallback(callback_function_type callback_function, void* userbdata);
```

I have successfully defined the required callback function type in python using `CFUNCTYPE()`, passed an instance of it to the C function, and verified that my callback function is executed when desired.

I have also successfully sent a simple type (i.e. `int`) as the `userdata` and accessed it in the callback.  However, sending complex types (i.e. custom classes) eludes me.

I need help figuring out how to 1) cast my `self` object to a `c_void_p` (as the `userdata` argument), and then 2) recover or cast back the `userdata` argument available in the callback to `self`'s original type for use in the callback.  (As in C++ which would be done by casting an object's `this` pointer to a `void*` and then casting back to its original type in the callback.)

Can someone help me get the correct syntax for "bundling up" `self` as a `c_void_p` and then "unbundling" back to its class type in the callback?

```
from ctypes import *
myClibrary = CDLL("myClibrary.so")
callback_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p)           # define type of callback function
RegisterCallback = myClibrary.RegCallback        # RegCallback is a C library function
RegisterCallback.argtypes = [callback_t, c_void_p]     # define its argument types
RegisterCallback.restype = c_int                       # define its result type

# define my callback function
def callback_fn(pArg):
    print('Hello from the callback function!')
    # I NEED TO BE ABLE TO ACCESS pArg as an instance of myClass type here in the callback

# construct global instance of the callback function which can be passed as argument to RegisterCallback
_callback_fn = callback_t(callback_fn)

# define custom class, instance of which needs to be passed to callback function
class myClass
    def __init__(self):
        userdata = c_void_p.from_buffer(py_object(self)).    # I think this is correct, but maybe not?
        retval = RegisterCallback(_callback_fn, userdata).   # register the callback function
```

These related questions are close but don't *quite* get to the answer I'm specifically looking for with the `self` object.  The general recommendation seems to be to use a lambda capture instead of a `c_void_p`, but I can't quite figure that out either.

[Pass Python object through void * and get back in callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349343/pass-python-object-through-void-and-get-back-in-callback)

[Python objects as userdata in ctypes callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469975/python-objects-as-userdata-in-ctypes-callback-functions)